# Prove that if $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$ iff $A=CB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations, fake-proofs

### The problem

Suppose $A,B \in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$.

I want to prove that $\text{null}(A)$ is the same as $\text{null}(B)$ if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $C$ such that $A=CB$.

### My solution

From the second half, $A=CB$ where $C$ is invertible implies $C$ is full-rank, therefore nullity of $C$ is the trivial zero. Therefore, $\text{null}(CB) = \text{null}(B) =\text{null}(A) $.

From the first side, if $\text{null}(A)=\text{null}(B)$, assuming we can write $A$ as $CB$ we can say $\text{null}(CB)=\text{null}(B)$. This means that the matrix $C$ as a linear transformation does not nullify anything in $B$. Since both $A$ and $B$ are $m \times n$ then $C$ must be $m \times m$. From the rank-nullity theorem, I can know that since $\text{null}(C)=0$ it is full-rank. So $C$ is invertible.

Am I thinking correctly?

Edit: re-wrote the whole question for comprehensibility.

Comment: If you only are given that $Ax = 0$ and $Bx = 0$ for one single $x$, you cannot deduce that their null spaces are equal. I suppose you actually want to show that ($Ax=0$ if and only if $Bx = 0$ for all $x$) implies $A=CB$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I re-wrote the question. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $A$ and $B$ have the same null space, then their row space must also coincide, as row spaces and null spaces are orthogonal complements. There is a result that matrices have the same row space iff they are row equivalent, i.e., we can obtain one from another by elementary row operations. Let $C$ be the product of corresponding elementary matrices, we get $A = CB$. For the other direction, you can verify that $Ax = 0$ iff $Bx =0$ with some invertible $C$ such that $A=CB$.

Your permutation matrix is a special case of the product of elementary matrices; specifically, row-interchanging ones. Note that there are also row-multiplication and row-addition elementary matrices.